# Verb Warning when loading modules with #Requires -Modules

Tags: powershell

I have a script which begins with:

```
#Requires -Modules ActiveDirectory, Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

which is all fine and dandy except that Sharepoint PS module throws a verb warning:

> WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell' include
>   unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the
>   Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.

I'd like to use the #Requires -Modules header in the script but suppress the warning.

I know there are ways to suppress all warnings in the shell before running the script but wondered if there was a better way to do it within the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if something like this might work:

```
$OriginalWarningPreference = $WarningPreference
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
#Requires -Modules ActiveDirectory, Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
$WarningPreference = $OriginalWarningPreference
```

Alternately, you can sacrifice some of the functionality of `#Requires` and do this:

```
#Requires -Modules ActiveDirectory
Import-Module -Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Nope. Still got the warning text. It did load the modules which is interesting because I thought that #Requires needed to be the first lines of the script but apparently not.  I am aware of how to import the module manually with the -EA Stop and -WA SilentlyContinue.  Was just wondering if there was a way to still use #Requires but with -DisableNameChecking or -WA SilentlyContinue built into it.

Comment: Ack. Tried to give you a +1 anyway for a valid workaround but I lack the rep. :'(

Answer (score 1):

a rather sneaky Workaround would be to use #requires only for the modules, that dont produce warnings and use

```
if (-not (get-module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell)) {
  Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -warningaction silentlycontinue
}
```

for the ones not strictly following naming conventions

Comment: Yes, that's how i've done it in other places.  Actually, just doing -EA stop and -WA SilentlyContinue would suffice to stop the scrip if the module failed and not display the warning.  Was trying to see if there was a way to do it with #Requires.

Comment: Ack. Tried to give you a +1 anyway for a valid workaround but I lack the rep. :'(